# Operating in a 2D list using 1-line nested for loop (list comprenhension)

Tags: python-3.6

I want each number in the 2D list 'a':

```
a=[[4, 3, 1], [-1, -2, -3]]
```

to make the operation

```
x*exp(-x)
```

so I can get a 2D list 'b' like:

```
b=[[0.073, 0.149, 0.367], [-2.718,-14.778,-60.256]]
```

and then sum both sub-lists separately to get a third list 'c' like:

```
c=[0.590,-77.753]
```

And I want it in 1 line nested for loop (using List Comprehension)

I tried this but it gives me a 1D list

```
b = [y*exp(-y) for x in a for y in x]
```

result:

```
b=[0.073, 0.149, 0.367, -2.718, -14.778, -60.256]
```

And I can't sum the sub-lists separately.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## List Comprehension (Naive method)

Exactly what you asked for:

```py
import math
a = [[4, 3, 1], [-1, -2, -3]]
b = [[y * math.exp(-y) for y in x] for x in a]
c = [sum(x) for x in b]
```

## Vectorized method

I would like to suggest an alternative method, that is more elegant and efficient as well - vectorized.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[4, 3, 1], [-1, -2, -3]])
b = a * np.exp(-a)
c = np.sum(b, axis=1)
```

Comment: Good. Didn't know about a vectorized version. I discovered this single line which does both the operation + the sum:
    c = [sum(x*exp(-x) for x in row) for row in a]